# PHP needs negative number first in switch statement

Tags: php, xampp, switch-statement

I have encountered a strange behavior on my XAMPP installation. A switch statement I had set up like this

```
case -1:
    ...
    break;
case 0:
    ...
    break;
case 1:
    ...
    break;
```

would execute correctly. However, the same thing turned around

```
case 1:
    ...
    break;
case 0:
    ...
    break;
case -1:
    ...
    break;
```

would work for 0 and 1, however, for -1 it would execute the case for 1.

Is this expected behavior or is it a bug in PHP?

//EDIT: Here is the full code (although I don´t think that it will be of any use): http://pastebin.com/ybsxH7gb

I have already rearranged th case statements, but before I had done that, it would not work.

Comment: Please show the variable you are testing.

Comment: PHP doesn't care about the order of case values in a switch statement, so please show the full statement and the type/value of the variable you are testing